# Adding values to act as breaks in array_merge dropdown

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, array-merge

I have three arrays getting different post types, which are then merged for a drop down in the Wordpress admin. I'm trying to insert empty values/breaks to make the drop down easier to read.

Here are the arrays and the array_merge:

```
// creating an array of pages

$featpages = array();
$pages = get_pages();
$pages[""] = "";
foreach ($pages as $page) {
$featpages[ $page->post_title ] = $page->ID;    
}

// creating an array of posts

$postargs = array('numberposts' => 0);
$featposts = array();
$posts = get_posts($postargs);
$posts[""] = "";
foreach ($posts as $post) {
$featposts[ $post->post_title ] = $post->ID;
}

// creating an array of activities

$actargs = array('post_type' => 'activity', 'numberposts' => 0);
$featacts = array();
$acts = get_posts($actargs);
$acts[""] = "";
foreach ($acts as $act) {
$featacts[ $act->post_title ] = $act->ID;
}

// creating a combined array of pages and tours

$links = array_merge((array)$featpages, (array)$featacts, (array)$featposts);
```

I was hoping the `[""] = "";`for each one would add an empty row between each set, but it only works for one - I guess because they look the same to the array_merge?

Comment: give each empty array a different key: posts['post_break'], acts['acts_break'] etc. but keep the value empty

Answer (score 0):

`[""] = "";` will overwrite the next one

Use `[] = '';` instead

Comment: Thanks! The first one still seems to be overwriting the second and third ones though...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to swap all of them for the latter example? Or is that what you did?

Comment: I tried both - swapping all of them for the latter example, and mixing different keys.

Comment: I think you may need to reconsider how you go about this, a space is more a graphical issue, shouldn't really prod the data to make it appear. Better to be able to say, when looping through "that was the last article/feature/etc so add a space in here".

Comment: Thanks for your help - you're right, it's entirely a visual thing - I just want to make the list clearer for the site admin - the dropdown basically allows them to link a slide on a homepage to another page on the site. The space is pretty much a last-minute detail!

Comment: Do you manually make that select/option HTML? If so you could make it multidimensional and then modify that code to look for a "type" so one entry would look like.. `$featpages[$page->post_title] = array('id'=>$page->ID,'type'=>'feature');` This improves data readability and code cleanliness. Theoretically :)